# Split multiple property values in JSON object array with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to convert the following JSON structure to CSV:

```
[
 {
   "node": "hosta;10.0.0.20;37038",
   "adjacency": "hostb;10.0.0.10;4001"
 },
 {
  "node": "hostc;10.0.0.16;52732",
  "adjacency": "hostd;10.0.0.24;4040"
 }
]
```

The CSV should look like this:

```
hosta,10.0.0.20,37038,hostb,10.0.0.10,4001
hostc,10.0.0.16,52732,hostd,10.0.0.24,4040
```

I know how to use the `split()` function to "explode" an individual property into three values using the semicolon as a divider - but how do I tell jq I want to split both the `node` and the `adjacency` property in the same pass?

(I can see how I might do this in Python with a more procedural approach, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing it with a function like `map()` in jq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array from each object that contains the two values, then use `map` to split the strings, `flatten` to join the resulting arrays, and `@csv` to produce the CSV output.

```
$ jq -r '.[] | [.node, .adjacency] | map (split(";")) | flatten | @csv' some.json
"hosta","10.0.0.20","37038","hostb","10.0.0.10","4001"
"hostc","10.0.0.16","52732","hostd","10.0.0.24","4040"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the strings to be quoted, and if you are sure that the quotation marks can be stripped off blindly, you could modify @chepner's answer by tacking on a call to `gsub/2`:

```
.[]
| [.node, .adjacency]
| map (split(";"))
| flatten
| @csv
| gsub("\"";"")
```

Similarly, if you only want the numbers in the output to be stripped of the quotation marks, you could add `map(tonumber?//.)` to the pipeline:

```
.[]
| [.node, .adjacency]
| map (split(";"))
| flatten
| map(tonumber?//.)
| @csv
```